# Find the Volume of the Solid--Cylindrical Shells

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified axis.

$$ y = 2x^2, x = 1, y = 0 $$

about the x-axis

I can't seem to get this. It's in a cylindrical shells section, but I don't see how it requires the use of cylindrical shells.

Comment: What is the specified axis? It can be done using either Shells or Slicing.

Comment: Oh sorry! It's about the x-axis

Comment: For shells, take a thin slice of width "$dy$" at height $y$ and rotate it. The radius of the shell is $y$, and the "height" of the cylinder is $1-x$, which is $1-\sqrt{y/2}$. So the shell has approximate volume $2\pi y(1-\sqrt{y/2})\,dy$. "Add up" (integrate) from $y=0$ to $y=2$. *Slicing* is far more pleasant, we get $\int_0^1 \pi (2x^2)^2\,dx$.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope the Shells setup is clear. The slicing setup is routine, you have done it many times.